# need help on while loop Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

first time on here. I'm trying to complete an application project regarding the while loop. I will paste the question in this and can anyone who has JavaScript knowledge give me a helping hand.

I've only just started out JavaScript probably about a month and a bit ago and struggle to remember everything. I've done a couple of while loops but until this question came up, it completed blanked my mind.

Here is the question;

Next,

create another HTML page with a  block in the  section of the document. This script should include the following:

Create a function named whileTest(). 
Inside the function, create a variable named number and assign it a value between 1 and 10.

Create another variable named answer and assign it a value of 0 (zero).
Then create a while loop. Create code that will cause the loop to execute as long as the number variable does not equal the answer variable.

Inside the loop, assign the answer variable the return value from a prompt dialog box.

The prompt will ask the user to guess a number between 1 and 10. The loop will continue until the proper answer is entered.

After the loop exits, use an alert dialog box to inform the user of a correct guess.

Once you have the code working properly, create code that will allow the user only three guesses. If, after three guesses, the user has not entered the correct answer, exit the function and alert the user that he or she is out of guesses via an alert dialog box.

Ensure that only one dialog box appears after the function is exited, one with a correct guess message, or one asking the user to try again.

Experiment with different methods that you have seen for calling the function. You can use the load event or the onclick event handler of a form button.

Comment: We expect you to show your effort, put the code you've tried to the question.

Comment: That's a small project of a guessing game but you didn't show any code so far!

Comment: sorry here is my effort;

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script>

function whileTest() {
  var num = 10;
  var answer = 0;
  while (num > 0) {
  num--;
  var answer = 0; prompt("Please guess a number between 1 and 10");
}

Comment: well change your post and include what you have tried so far and what problems you have found, to make sure your post doesn't get closed

Answer (score 0):

Here I made you a startup, you can develop it to a full guessing game, happy coding :)

```js
function playAgainCheck() {
  if(confirm("Do you want to play Again?")) {
    whileTest();
  }
}

function whileTest() {
  var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1, guess, i = 1;
  do {
    guess = prompt("Guess a number between 1 and 10 (both included)");
    if(guess == n) {
      alert("You won!");
      playAgainCheck();
      break;
    }
    if(i++ === 3) {
      alert("Out of guesses!\nThe number was: " + n);
      playAgainCheck();
      break;
    }
  } while(true);
}

whileTest();
```

Comment: this is what ive got;

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script>

function whileTest() {
  var num = 10;
  var answer = 0;
  while (num > 0) {
  num--;
  var answer = 0; prompt("Please guess a number between 1 and 10");
}

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script>

function whileTest() {
  var num = 10;
  var answer = 0;
  while (num > 0) {
  num--;
  var answer = 0; prompt("Please guess a number between 1 and 10");
}

Comment: why n-- and while(n > 0), pls see my post it helps you start coding that game, you need to get the number each time from the user and check against your number, not to decrement your number!

Comment: the reason ive used num-- instead of num++ because im going from 10 to 0 not 0 to 10. ive looked at yours and ran the snippet which worked but when trying it into atom, it didn't work.

Comment: with your example, how would you alter it so the person only gets 3 guesses to get the correct answer of 6? so have var num=10;  var answer 1, prompt("please guess a number between 1 and 10"); and if they don't guess the correct answer within 3 tries, then they get an alert saying they have ran out of guesses.

Comment: I don't get it why even loop from 1 to 10 or 10 to 1, it's not required in your post!, ok I got it, you want to change the number, you need to make it random but only at the beginning cause you can't guess a changing number!!!

Comment: Go and take a look I have edited my post as required from your post.